# How do I get Spring REST Template to log the JAXB marshalled XML ?

Tags: spring, jaxb, resttemplate

Using Spring REST Template to make requests.  Springs internal JAXB converter takes my JAXB pojo and marshals it to xml for the request body.  How do I get this XML into the logs for debugging purposes?